# Add post's category as a meta tag to the post

Tags: post-meta

For tracking purposes, I need to add a meta tag to each blog post with the post category it's in.

The meta tag would need to look like this:

```
<meta name="category" content="politics">
```

I'm not too familiar with .PHP, but is there a specific snippet I can add to functions.php that would accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: is this tracking you're adding yourself or is this a requirement of a library you're using? Or are you doing this for Google

Comment: Our ad network needs a category meta tag to track ad performance per post category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below snippet to achieve the result.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_407790_add_meta_tags_to_post' );
/**
 * Add category meta tags to post.
 */
function so_407790_add_meta_tags_to_post() {

    // Get the current page categories.
    $categories = get_the_category();

    if ( ! $categories ) {
        return;
    }

    // Category slug into list with comma separated.
    $category_list = implode( ',', wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'slug' ) );

    // Add meta tags to the head.
    echo '<meta name="category" content="' . esc_attr( $category_list ) . '" />';
}
```

Comment: This is stellar - works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.